# Confluent 4.0.0 Kafka Connect - Schema Registry Subject Not Found : org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException:

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry, ksqldb

I have checked the 2 similar issues but it doesn't help.

```
node 1 [/appl/node1/confluent-4.0.0] ./bin/confluent status elasticsearch-sink


{"name":"elasticsearch-sink","connector":{"state":"RUNNING","worker_id":"10.192.226.24:8083"},"tasks":[{"state":"FAILED","trace":"org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException:
emailfilters\n\tat
io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter.toConnectData(AvroConverter.java:96)\n\tat
org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:453)\n\tat
org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:287)\n\tat
org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:198)\n\tat
org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:166)\n\tat
org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:170)\n\tat
org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:214)\n\tat
java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)\n\tat
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)\n\tat
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)\n\tat
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)\n\tat
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)\nCaused by:
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error
retrieving Avro schema for id 21\nCaused by:
io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.exceptions.RestClientException:
Subject not found.; error code: 40401\n\tat
io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.sendHttpRequest(RestService.java:191)\n\tat
io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.httpRequest(RestService.java:218)\n\tat
io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.lookUpSubjectVersion(RestService.java:284)\n\tat
io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.lookUpSubjectVersion(RestService.java:272)\n\tat
io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.getVersionFromRegistry(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:71)\n\tat
io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.getVersion(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:182)\n\tat
io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.deserialize(AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.java:152)\n\tat
io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.deserializeWithSchemaAndVersion(AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.java:194)\n\tat
io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter$Deserializer.deserialize(AvroConverter.java:121)\n\tat
io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter.toConnectData(AvroConverter.java:84)\n\tat
org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:453)\n\tat
org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:287)\n\tat
org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:198)\n\tat
org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:166)\n\tat
org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:170)\n\tat
org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:214)\n\tat
java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)\n\tat
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)\n\tat
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)\n\tat
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)\n\tat
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)\n","id":0,"worker_id":"10.192.226.24:8083"}],"type":"sink"}
```

my properties :

```
name=elasticsearch-sink
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector
tasks.max=1
topics=emailfilters
key.ignore=true
connection.url=http://127.0.0.1:9197
type.name=kafka-connect
```

tried adding the following but still get the same error.

```
value.converter=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
value.converter.schema.registry.url=http://node1:9193
```

My topic is being populated from KSQL stream.

Answer (score 1):

This is the cause of the failure:

```
Caused by:
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error
retrieving Avro schema for id 21\nCaused by:
io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.exceptions.RestClientException:
Subject not found.; error code: 40401
```

This means that the Schema Registry you've defined doesn't have the schema for the data on the topic. Are you specifying the same Schema Registry in your Connector config as you are using with KSQL?

Comment: Yes  I am using the same schema registry in ksql and connect as well.

Comment: I have tested the Elastic Search Connect today with a topic which is not being generated by KSQL and the schema is writing to the destination elastic search indices properly. I will test the KSQL once again and I will let you know.

Comment: I've run into the same error with a different connector. The schema exists, and the logs for the schema registry returns an HTTP code 200 for the response, but then it gets a 404 when trying to post to `/subjects/{topic-name}-key?deleted=true`. Not sure why it's trying to do that because it can decode the value just fine with just the schema. But essentially my issue is that I encode a message with a subject name that doesn't match what the connector assumes.

Comment: @tytho you're probably best off starting a new question with full details of your setup, version, config, etc.

Comment: Apologies, wasn't meant to ask more about my issue. We've since found a different workaround, just thought I'd add some detail to the behavior of the connector.

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed if using `key.converter` to Avro, then it will still try to extract a schema from string, ints, etc. non-avro datatypes, then give these confusing errors. The only validation it checks if it the byte payload starts with a `0`, then just gets the next 4 bytes, which doesn't really say that it definitely is not Avro.

Check the datatype for your topic's key, then check your Connect properties

Answer (score 0):

kafka connector configs should contains the below config field as well

```
"value.converter.value.subject.name.strategy": "io.confluent.kafka.serializers.subject.RecordNameStrategy"
```

*There are few other avro subject identification strategies* [more](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/serdes-develop/index.html#subject-name-strategy)

Since the topic data can contain multiple avro schema types we need to provide a way to identify the right data type according to the specific record